# Hide optional navbar menus when Logged In - Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular8

I'm trying to hide some of my navbar menus after I logged in.

Here is my navbar menus

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="books">Books</a></li> 
  <!--Hide this link-->  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="sign-in">Sign In</a></li> 
  <!--Hide this link-->  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="sign-up">Sign Up</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to hide these commented links that I want to hide? here is my **SignIn Component Type Script**

```
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  email: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login(){
    this.auth.login(this.email, this.password);
    this.email = this.password = '';
  }

}
```

**Auth Service Type Script**

```
  login(email: string, password: string){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
      value => {
        console.log('Success!', value);
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      }
    ).catch(err=>{
      console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      this.router.navigate(['sign-up']);
    })
  }
```

** If this will help, here is my **Header Type Script**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Book List App';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just bind them to a Boolean value that gets true then a user is logged in.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer - thank you sir, can you please show me a preference, I just dived directly to the login system and follow a tutorial, as you can see I'm still learning angular :) thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using angular firebase, so you can listen to the `authState`, which returns you an observable of `firebase.User` when logged in or `null` when not logged in. It emits every time when the auth state changes. You can use the auth state in a service, store it in a variable so that it is usable all over the app. Components then subscribe to the observable.

Service:

```
import { User } from 'firebase';

// ...

user$: Observable<User>;

constructor(...) {
   this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState;
}
```

Component:

```
import { User } from 'firebase';
import { AuthService } from '....'

// ...

user$: Observable<User>;

contructor(private authService: AuthService) { 
  this.user$ = this.authService.user$;
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="!user$ | async">...</div> 
<div *ngIf="user$ | async">...</div>
```

You can also use `*ngIf ... else` if you don't want two `*ngIf`'s.

Comment: I have a question in the component - which component is it? the `Header` or the `SignIn` Component?

Comment: Well, the component(s) where you want to hide/show the content based on the logged in status. I guess it would be the navbar component, as it's there you want to hide/show links?

Comment: gotcha! but my service is `import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";` then in my constructor it is `this.user$ = this.AuthService.user$;` but the error says **Property 'AuthService' does not exist on type 'HeaderComponent'.**

Comment: have you injected the service in the constructor?

Comment: you need to inject the service in the component constructor... like `private authService: AuthService`, then call `this.user$ = this.authService.user$`

Comment: - `constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
    this.user$ = this.auth.user$;
  }` am i correct? but the output was: the links are automatically hidden even I haven't logged in yet.

Comment: You are correct, but they cannot both be hidden. `user$` cannot be both `true` and `false` at the same time! have you checked the template I posted closely?

Comment: learnt so much from you today sir! Godbless! great for beginner's like me diving to the essential lvls of angular

Comment: Great, glad to hear, and I am happy to help! Have a nice end of the weekend and happy coding! :)

Comment: if you have time, can you please spare time also with my bug code here please. Im trying my best to understand the operations but Im running problems that i cannot deal with since yesterday here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645988/data-is-unknown-cannot-be-fetched-when-link-is-clicked-after-implementing-rou)

Answer (score 2):

Return a boolean value true/false based on the success,

```
boolean login(email: string, password: string){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
      value => {
        console.log('Success!', value);
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        return true;
      }
    ).catch(err=>{
      console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      this.router.navigate(['sign-up']);
      return false;
    })
  }
```

and assign to a variable in your component as,

```
this.loggedIn =   this.auth.login(this.email, this.password);;
```

bind the variable in your HTML

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="loggedIn"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="sign-in">Sign In</a></li> 
<li class="nav-item"  *ngIf="loggedIn"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="sign-up">Sign Up</a></li>
```

Comment: @Sajeeetharan hi! thank you! But my other functions got error when I add boolean on the login, also the components also has an error `Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.` thank you again sir

Answer (score 0):

You can save to session storage state of login or not.

```
login(email: string, password: string){
        this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
          value => {
            sessionStorage.setItem("loggedIn", email);
            console.log('Success!', value);
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
          }
        ).catch(err=>{
          console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
          this.router.navigate(['sign-up']);
        })
      }
```

And add a variable flag to check logged in or not

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Book List App';

  isLoggedIn : boolean;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedIn") != undefined;
  }

}
```

Update html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="books">Books</a></li> 
  <!--Hide this link-->  <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="sign-in">Sign In</a></li> 
  <!--Hide this link-->  <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="sign-up">Sign Up</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! but there's an error on this line  `sessionStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
` stating **Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.** and also error on this line `isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedIn") == true;` stating **This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'true' have no overlap.**

Comment: sir it has an error `value = storage[key]

This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'true' have no overlap.`

Comment: I updated answer you can set sessionStorage.setItem("loggedIn", email);

Comment: Thank you! Updated output: There is no error but the link is still showing after logged in, it doesnt hide. Isn't there any changes will be done in the sign-in component.ts sir? thank you again :)

Comment: did you update onInit method isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedIn") != undefined;

Comment: yes sir, as what your code looks like, I double checked it also, it has no errors but the menu links still showing.

Comment: Go to application tab and clear session storage please

Comment: I have a logout button but it just go back to the sign-in html\

Comment: Great! but now the links that I want to hide is hidden even I haven't logged in yet. they are hidden when Im not logged in.

Comment: did you check in application tab, session item with key loggedIn exist?